# Add / Remove buttons in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nsbox

I have a Source-View (`NSOutlineView`) with two Buttons at the bottom. I added an `NSBox` so that the items don't "shine through" when they're behind the buttons.

This works fine when the window is active:

[image]

But as soon as I deactivate the window the `NSBox` still has that active color, rather than a dimmed version to match the `NSOutlineView`'s background color:

[image]

How can I make sure that those two colors always match. Also using a specific color is a bit of a hack since the color `NSOutline` uses might change at some point.

**Update**: Apple's Mail.app as well as [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) seem to have a solution for that problem. :-/

Comment: No, do you have one? :-) I am currently using the NSView to shield the buttons from the scroll view in the background. However, Apple Mail does that and Things (from Cultured Code). I wonder how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

@Neha put me on the right way to find a solution.

I write it in Ruby because I work with Rubymotion but it's easy to translate :)

Assuming you have a `box` outlet for the NSBox, you can set it to transparent when the window loses the focus and do the opposite when it becomes the key window, using the appropriate delegate methods:

```rb
  def windowDidBecomeKey(notification)
    box.setTransparent(false)
  end

  def windowDidResignKey(notification)
    box.setTransparent(true)
  end
```

And the result looks fine with the focus:

[image]

And without it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to keep a reference to the NSOutlineView's `backgroundColor` property as it is a special `NSColor` that dynamically changes depending on the key status of the parent window. Set the color of your custom view to that that reference. When the window loses/gains key status, call `setNeedsDisplay:` on your custom view to redraw it using the new color. Use KVO to observe `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` and `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification`. Note that pointer to the color stays the same, but the actual color represented by the reference changes. The solution is explained [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/211083-sourcelist-background-colors.html#211153).

Answer (score 0):

In the attributes inspector of `NSBox`,
set display to transparent

Comment: Well but then the items "shine through" again and I wouldn't need the box in the first place